# Concatinating JSON elements using java-json

Tags: java, csv, json

I have a program that reads in a `CSV` file and returns a `JSON` `String.`

However using [JsonArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [JsonObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) only yield the last row of results from the file. How do I concat numerous rows of data into a JSON object?

**Output**

```
[{"name":"Other_Renwables","load":"14.3"},{"name":"Other_Renwables","load":"14.3"},{"name":"Other_Renwables","load":"14.3"},{"name":"Other_Renwables","load":"14.3"},{"name":"Other_Renwables","load":"14.3"},{"name":"Other_Renwables","load":"14.3"}]
```

**Code**

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
        int count = 0;

         try{  
             logger.info("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
             HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
             HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
             int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
             logger.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);
             if (responseCode != 404){
                 try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent()))) {
                     if(reader != null){
                         //StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                         String aux = "";
                         while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                             String[] tab = aux.split(",");
                             if (count > 0){
                                 try {
                                    jObject.put("name", tab[0]);
                                    jObject.put("load", tab[1]);
                                    jArray.put(jObject);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                             }
                             count++;

                            }

                            retVal = jArray.toString();
                     }
                 }

              }
             return retVal;
         }finally{
             httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
         }
```

Comment: Why testing for a null reader? It can never be null. If it is, you don't even enter the try block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same object and over-writing it in your loop.
This instantiation:

```
 JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
```

must be in your loop.

```
 try {
     JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
     jObject.put("name", tab[0]);
     jObject.put("load", tab[1]);
     jArray.put(jObject);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize a new Object had to be created each time